# Flattening and combining WCF service resultset for display in SSRS report

Tags: wcf, reporting-services

We have a WCF service that returns the following:

```
MessageContract
    |
    +-- List<TopLevelDataContract>

TopLevelDataContract
    |
    +-- FirstChildDataContract
    +-- SecondChildDataContract
    +-- ThirdChildDataContract

FirstChildDataContract
    |
    +-- FieldOne
    +-- AnotherField

SecondChildDataContract
    |
    +-- FieldTwo
    +-- YetAnotherField

ThirdChildDataContract
    |
    +-- FieldThree
    +-- AndAnotherField
```

To adequately display these datacontracts in SSRS, we need to flatten them into a tabular form like so:

```
+----------+--------------+----------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
| FieldOne | AnotherField | FieldTwo | YetAnotherField | FieldThree | AndAnotherField |
+----------+--------------+----------+-----------------+------------+-----------------+
 ... rows of data...
```

However the `ElementPath` expression/XMLDP query to achieve this is eluding us. We've tried the following without joy:

1. Gets all "rows" of a the `FirstChildDataContract` type:

```
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">   
  MessageContract{}/TopLevelDataContracts{}/TopLevelDataContract{}/FirstChildDataContract
</ElementPath>
```

1. This gets all the children, but in raw XML format:

```
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">   
  MessageContract{}/TopLevelDataContracts{}/TopLevelDataContract{@}
</ElementPath>
```

1. This does the same as (1):

```
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">   
  *
</ElementPath>
```

What is the correct `ElementPath` expression to use to achieve this, if possible?

(aside: And why didn't Microsoft just use XPath, which is well-documented and flexible, instead of rolling their own almost-but-not-quite-like-xpath query language?)

Comment: Wow, I did not even know you could bind SSRS to WCF.  Good job if you have got it that far.  SSRS is mostly made with SQL, ODBC, Sharepoint, Raw XML in mind.  Is there are security or overhead risk associated with just putting a datasource in SSRS directly to a database?  Or is the data being sent by the service not from a database directly?  I think using an RDLC file in Visual Studio directly may be a better method as I believe you can consume WCF and make generic POCO Lists to pass to it. The amount of work it may take to use SSRS may be a lot but I am very curious if someone else answers.

Comment: No experience using WCF and SSRS, but I was curious enough to dig up some other stuff on it. Would an approach like this work for you? http://devblog.bardoloi.com/2011/09/using-wcf-web-services-as-data-source.html

Answer (score 0):

I've read this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964129(SQL.90).aspx

It stated that

> Multiple parent-child hierarchies are not supported. In this example, Customer has both Orders and Returns. The provider may return only one set. Because the Orders hierarchy is specified first, auto-derivation will resolve it as the skeleton.

I don't know much about SSRS but Im thinking of using multiple dataset as a trick. Is it possible?